# jquery dropdown menu

Tags: jquery, menu, drop-down-menu

how can i change this code so that the menu drops down when the `("ul.topnav li")` is hovered and not the `<span>`.  when i changed the code all the `("ul.subnav)` dropped when hovered over.

thanks,

```
<script language="javascript"  type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

       $("ul.subnav").parent().append("<span></span>");

       //When trigger is clicked...
       $("ul.topnav li span").mouseenter(function() { 

            //Following events are applied to the subnav itself 
            //(moving subnav up and down)

            //Drop down the subnav on click
            $(this).parent().find("ul.subnav").slideDown('fast').show(); 

            $(this).parent().hover(function() {
            }, function() {
                //When the mouse hovers out of the subnav, move it back up
                $(this).parent().find("ul.subnav").slideUp('slow'); 
            });

        //Following events are applied to the trigger 

        }).hover(function() { //(Hover events for the trigger)

            $(this).addClass("subhover"); //On hover over, add class "subhover"
        }, function() { //On Hover Out

            //On hover out, remove class "subhover"
            $(this).removeClass("subhover"); 
        });

    });


</script>
```

Comment: I think that you are selecting the parent of the ul nav which is sliding all of the sub navs to slide down this.slidetoggle()

Answer (score 2):

When you change the `.mouseenter()` event attachment to the `li`, it changes the scope of everything inside the function.   Fortunately, all the code within just tries to get back up to the parent `li` of the `span` it was originally targeting.  So, to fix this. you just remove the calls to `parent()` where appropriate.

```
<script language="javascript"  type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

       $("ul.subnav").parent().append("<span></span>");

       //When trigger is clicked...
       $("ul.topnav li").mouseenter(function() { 

            //Following events are applied to the subnav itself 
            //(moving subnav up and down)

            //Drop down the subnav on click
            $(this).find("ul.subnav").slideDown('fast').show(); 

            $(this).parent().hover(function() {},
            function() {
                //When the mouse hovers out of the subnav, move it back up
                $(this).find("ul.subnav").slideUp('slow'); 
            });

        //Following events are applied to the trigger 

        }).hover(function() { //(Hover events for the trigger)

            $(this).addClass("subhover"); //On hover over, add class "subhover"
        }, function() { //On Hover Out

            //On hover out, remove class "subhover"
            $(this).removeClass("subhover"); 
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Didn't' see your comment \: Can't mark comments as accepted answers, so this question would never get "closed" without an answer \:

Comment: no no agreed I wasnt sure about my answer so I commented I am glad that you answered it. I just didn't want to put a half answer in the "answer"